# Grouping WHERE clause in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a query like this.

```
WHERE (timetable_id = '1' 
       OR timetable_id = '2' 
       OR timetable_id = '3' 
       OR timetable_id = '4' 
       OR timetable_id = '5' 
       OR timetable_id = '6')

AND exam_name_id = '5'
```

But I don't know how to execute this in **Codeigniter**.

I have tried this

```
while(@$i <= 6 {                         
   $this->db->or_where('timetable_id',$this->input->post('timetable_id'.$i));
   $i++;   
   }                    
$this->db->where('et.exam_name_id',5);
```

But the above command gives output like this

```
WHERE timetable_id = '1'
      OR timetable_id = '2' 
      OR timetable_id = '3' 
      OR timetable_id = '4' 
      OR timetable_id = '5' 
      OR timetable_id = '6'
      AND et.exam_name_id = '5'
```

This gives all the outputs. How to do that correctly?
Please Note in my query I have `()` braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@$i = 1;
$n = $this->input->post('timetable_id'.$i);
$or_where = "(";
$or_where.="timetable_id = $n";
for ($i; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    $n = $this->input->post('timetable_id'.$i);
    $or_where.=" OR timetable_id = $n";
}
$or_where.=")";     
$this->db->or_where($or_where);
```

This will give your expected answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you using `CI 3.xx` version then you can use

```
$this->db->group_start();
while($i <= 6) {                         
   $this->db->or_where('timetable_id',$this->input->post('timetable_id'.$i));
   $i++;   
   }                    
$this->db->group_end();
$this->db->where('et.exam_name_id',5);
```

In `CI 2.xx` version pass condition in string

Comment: It said `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::group_start()`

Comment: sorry, just saw... you have also posted answer... `group_start()` and `group_end()` function available in `CI 3.xx` and probably you are using `CI 2.xx`

Comment: @PraveenSrinivasan see this http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Answer (score 0):

Youre making it difficult for yourself using that while loop. Also, i dont understand why you are using `$this->input->post()` if you are building the numbers with your loop. I would use a `for` loop like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    $this->db->or_where('timetable_id', $i);
}
$this->db->where('et.exam_name_id', 5);
```

Comment: I am getting same out as I got before

Comment: I have a counting in my view page, so that I am using `$this->input->post()`

Comment: ok. please edit your OP (Original Post) and provide your controller and your view in order to further understand what you are trying to accomplish